# Quickest way of applying thesis to tex template

Tags: errors, compiling, paths

I am trying to apply my thesis to a TeX template. I have `pdflatex` installed on a Linux box (in my university), but cannot get it to work. When I point to my TeX file as below, it gives an error:

```
Enter file name: /users/ugrad/oconnorp/Downloads/CUEDThesisPSnPDF/thesis
! LaTeX Error: File `Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). are you using [CUED zip file](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/CUEDThesisPSnPDF.zip) for your thesis writing. Do you have any [LaTeX editor](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/15717) to open/edit/compile the `thesis.tex` file ? you have to build upon and type on the `thesis.tex` to get your thesis writing going.

Comment: You're missing some files that were used to make the template. See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages). Probably on the school website somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome!  Yes. I have a text editor but no tex\latex editor(i checked the computer for one but they dont seem to have one installed- i tried installing one- but it said i am not in sudoers file- and this has been reported :-) )- im on ubuntu and it does have pdflatex on the command line, so i thought running the command and pointing to the folder would work! Maybe it could be a problem with the template?

Comment: @user2152812 can you see any latex editor in programming section ? if you have `sudo` rights to install see the [latex editor](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402/15717) and install from [website](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html)/synaptic manager. the [zip file template](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/CUEDThesisPSnPDF.zip) works fine. there is no error. check your folder `Classes` for `CUEDthesisPSnPDF.cls`, your are missing that in your compilation, hence the error.

Comment: Yeah i do have it in the folder- so it seems that some other file is not pointing to it correctly. Unfortunately i cannot install any editors on this computer. I tried with the zip as opposed to the tar version. the error is more specific:  Undefined control sequence.
l.4  \documentclass
                   [oneside,12pt]{Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF}

Comment: @user2152812 A latex editor might be already installed. Which version of Ubuntu are you using ? latex editor is just for comfort of user experience. One can always use any ascii text editor to type the thesis and save as .tex to run from command line terminal. to test, you can download the new template. In my view your changed the default template  `\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF}`. Download a 32bit linux [portable version of TeXmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/texmaker_linux32.tar.gz) binary which does not need installation, just doubleclick on executable.

Comment: @user2152812   test whether your linux is 32 bit or 64 bit using `uname -a` at terminal. install 32(i386) or 64 bit(x86_64) as per ur response from terminal.

Comment: thanks a lot i installed the 32 bit one(even though it is 64 bit- it appears to work fine). However, it seems there is an issue with the template,as it does not display in the pdf view

Comment: @user2152812 what's the error ? you can see the `thesis.log` for any errors/warnings. you cannot chat unless you have 20 rep. try with a [simple example](http://www.andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/hello.tex)

Comment: Have it working now- thank you so much!!! texenthusiast can you post in answer question and i will mark it as answered thanks.

Comment: How are you 'applying' your thesis to a template?  This sounds confusing to me.  Can you run any version of `latex` at all?  For instance what happens when you try the following (in a folder you have write permissions): `latex small2e` (or `pdflatex small2e`)?

Comment: @user2152812 great news. i will post my comment as answer in few min after food.

Comment: @user2152812 after some time of struggle i could retrace the error your got and the reason for it. you did not change the directory to the `cd /users/ugrad/oconnorp/Downloads/CUEDThesisPSnPDF` before running `pdflatex` from the `CUEDThesisPSnPDF` directory. hence the .cls(class)/.sty(style) file location was not known to `pdflatex` engine. Instead you ran `pdflatex` from a different directory, but did not provide name of the `.tex` file and the location of `.cls and .sty files`. Moral: Run `pdflatex thesis` after the `cd /users/ugrad/oconnorp/Downloads/CUEDThesisPSnPDF` directory.

Comment: @user2152812 Command line Terminal way of running `pdflatex fileName.tex` should  work always. ideally there is no need for latex editor, its for GUI user experience and synctex/view pdf facilities.

Answer (score 6):

**Reason for the error**:

- There is no change in directory by `cd
  /users/ugrad/oconnorp/Downloads/CUEDThesisPSnPDF` before running
  pdflatex from the CUEDThesisPSnPDF directory.
- `cd` should be done as `CUEDthesisPSnPDF.cls` (class file) is located
  in `Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF` where the `pdflatex` would be searching as it is 
  mentioned in the argument of `\documentclass[]{}` as below.

  ```
    \documentclass[oneside,12pt]{Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF}
  ```
- Hence the .cls(class)/.sty(style) file location was not known to
  `pdflatex` engine. Instead you ran `pdflatex` from a different directory,
  but did not provide name of the .tex file and the location of .cls
  and .sty files. Program was just exited by typing `X`.

**Correct Approach**

- Run `pdflatex thesis` after the `cd
  /users/ugrad/oconnorp/Downloads/CUEDThesisPSnPDF` to satisfy the
  `CUEDthesisPSnPDF.cls` location at `Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF`
- Command line/Terminal way of running `pdflatex fileName.tex` should
  work always and its the best verification test incase of errors from
  Editors. Ideally there is no need for latex editor, its for GUI user
  experience and synctex/view pdf facilities.

**Verify a latex installation: Commandline/Terminal**:

- To verify/test a latex installation(TeXlive or MiKTeX) using
  commandline/terminal, one can use

`latex small2e` to get the `small2e.dvi` (or)

`latex sample2e` to get the `sample2e.dvi`

`pdflatex small2e` to get the `small2e.pdf` (or)

`pdflatex sample2e` to get the `sample2e.pdf`

`pdflatex sample2e` to get the `sample2e.pdf`

`xetex opentype-info` to get the `opentype-info.pdf`

Notice, there is no need for `.tex` extension

Mentioned by: [jon in his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101878/quickest-way-of-applying-thesis-to-tex-template#comment221384_101878)

**Portable LaTeX editor: Without sudo rights**:

- When one don't have a LaTeX editor installed on Ubuntu and also don't
  have `sudo/admin` rights. use [portable version of TeXmaker LaTeX
  editor](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/texmaker_linux32.tar.gz)
  depending on the 32bit(i386) or 64 bit (x86_64) linux.
- Test whether linux is 32 bit or 64 bit using `uname -a` at
  terminal. 32bit portable editor can run on both.