# How to run MiKTex FNDB on Windows 8?

Tags: miktex

Apologies for the inane question, but I can't figure out how to run MiKTex FNDB on Windows 8.  On Windows 7 and earlier, I simply followed:

Start → Programs → MiKTeX 2.9 → Maintenance

Of course the Start Menu on Windows 8 does not exist.  So how do I follow this on path Windows 8?

Thanks!

Comment: I answered my own question. This is the location of the "MikTek Options" executable:  C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\mo_admin.    Still, it would be nice if there were a more user friendly way to get here...

Comment: The author of MiKTeX has a (rather old) [blog post on this topic](http://blog.miktex.org/post/2011/09/15/MiKTeX-on-Windows-8.aspx). Windows 8 automatically makes Start screen tiles for every Start menu item, but in Windows 8.1, they are not automatically pinned.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running **Windows 8** (without the 8.1 update), all new shortcuts that would be added to the old Start menu are pinned as tiles to the Start screen, as in this screenshot from the MiKTeX [author's blog](http://blog.miktex.org/post/2011/09/15/MiKTeX-on-Windows-8.aspx):

[image: MiKTeX tiles on the Windows Start Screen]

**Windows 8.1** avoids cluttering your Start screen by *not* automatically pinning new tiles; to access these tiles, swipe up from the bottom of the screen and then to the right. Holding down a tile (or right-clicking it) allows you to pin it to the Start screen.