# Issues with installing "tikz-cd" and "arrows.meta"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an up-to-date MikTeX 2.9 installation with tikz/pgf 3.0, but trying to compile

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

it says: I can't find file tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex

i tried to do as mentioned here: [arrows.meta in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165585/arrows-meta-in-tikz/168005#168005)

but it still doesn't work.

I also cannot use the package {arrows.meta} but i suggest, this goes with tikz-cd?

I did the whole update thing (plane and Administrator) but nothing changed.

---

S. Segletes providing this edit.  I, too receive this error on one of my systems.  I am using MikTeX.  Here is the log file, with `\listfiles` added to the preamble, as Paul Gessler suggests:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.8.23)  11 APR 2014 00:07
entering extended mode
**C:/Users/Steven/TeX/junk.tex
(C:/Users/Steven/TeX/junk.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls\amsart.cls"
Document Class: amsart 2009/07/02 v2.20.1
\linespacing=\dimen102
\normalparindent=\dimen103
\normaltopskip=\skip41
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip42

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen104
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen105
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count79
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count80
\leftroot@=\count81
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
\classnum@=\count82
\DOTSCASE@=\count83
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen106
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
\macc@depth=\count84
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count85
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count86
\dspbrk@lvl=\count87
\tag@help=\toks15
\row@=\count88
\column@=\count89
\maxfields@=\count90
\andhelp@=\toks16
\eqnshift@=\dimen107
\alignsep@=\dimen108
\tagshift@=\dimen109
\tagwidth@=\dimen110
\totwidth@=\dimen111
\lineht@=\dimen112
\@envbody=\toks17
\multlinegap=\skip43
\multlinetaggap=\skip44
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 388.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd"
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
\copyins=\insert233
\abstractbox=\box28
\listisep=\skip45
\c@part=\count91
\c@section=\count92
\c@subsection=\count93
\c@subsubsection=\count94
\c@paragraph=\count95
\c@subparagraph=\count96
\c@figure=\count97
\c@table=\count98
\abovecaptionskip=\skip46
\belowcaptionskip=\skip47
\captionindent=\dimen113
\thm@style=\toks19
\thm@bodyfont=\toks20
\thm@headfont=\toks21
\thm@notefont=\toks22
\thm@headpunct=\toks23
\thm@preskip=\skip48
\thm@postskip=\skip49
\thm@headsep=\skip50
\dth@everypar=\toks24
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz.st
y (C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgf.sty
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.sty
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-c
ommon.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks25
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-l
atex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box29
 (C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.co
de.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
))
Package: pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)

(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.st
y ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks26
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count99
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen114
\Gin@req@width=\dimen115
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.st
y
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.
code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)

(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.c
ode.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks27
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks28

(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfi
ltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks29
))
\pgf@x=\dimen116
\pgf@y=\dimen117
\pgf@xa=\dimen118
\pgf@ya=\dimen119
\pgf@xb=\dimen120
\pgf@yb=\dimen121
\pgf@xc=\dimen122
\pgf@yc=\dimen123
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count100
\c@pgf@countb=\count101
\c@pgf@countc=\count102
\c@pgf@countd=\count103

(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Package pgfsys Info: Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def on input line 900.

(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-
pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2009/05/22  (rcs-revision 1.26)

(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-
common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2008/05/19  (rcs-revision 1.10)
)))
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsyss
oftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count104
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count105
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsysp
rotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
))
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.
code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)

(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.t
ex
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.co
de.tex
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.co
de.tex)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.
code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen124
\pgfmath@count=\count106
\pgfmath@box=\box30
\pgfmath@toks=\toks30
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks31
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks32
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.code.tex
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.basic.code.tex)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.trigonometric.code.tex)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.random.code.tex)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.comparison.code.tex)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.base.code.tex)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.round.code.tex)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.misc.code.tex)))
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.c
ode.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count107
))
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorep
oints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2010/04/09  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen125
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen126
\pgf@picminy=\dimen127
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen128
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen129
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen130
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen131
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen132
\pgf@xx=\dimen133
\pgf@xy=\dimen134
\pgf@yx=\dimen135
\pgf@yy=\dimen136
\pgf@zx=\dimen137
\pgf@zy=\dimen138
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorep
athconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2010/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen139
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen140
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorep
athusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2008/04/22  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen141
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen142
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcores
copes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2010/09/08  (rcs-revision 1.34)
\pgfpic=\box31
\pgf@hbox=\box32
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box33
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count108
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreg
raphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2008/04/22  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen143
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoret
ransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2009/06/10  (rcs-revision 1.11)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen144
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen145
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen146
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreq
uick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreo
bjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorep
athprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.8)
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorea
rrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2008/04/23  (rcs-revision 1.11)
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcores
hade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2008/11/23  (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgf@max=\dimen147
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count109
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorei
mage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2010/03/25  (rcs-revision 1.16)

(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoree
xternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2010/09/01  (rcs-revision 1.17)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box34
))
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorel
ayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2010/08/27  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoret
ransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2008/01/17  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorep
atterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2009/07/02  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)))
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmodulesh
apes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2010/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box35
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmodulepl
ot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2010/10/22  (rcs-revision 1.8)
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp
-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen148
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen149
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp
-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgffor.sty
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.sty

(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.c
ode.tex))
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgffor.co
de.tex
Package: pgffor 2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen150
\pgffor@skip=\dimen151
\pgffor@stack=\toks33
\pgffor@toks=\toks34
))
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\
tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)

(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibrar
yplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2010/05/31 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count110
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen152
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen153
\tikz@lasty=\dimen154
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen155
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen156
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen157
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen158
\tikz@figbox=\box36
\tikz@tempbox=\box37
\tikztreelevel=\count111
\tikznumberofchildren=\count112
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count113
\tikz@fig@count=\count114

(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmodulema
trix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2010/08/24  (rcs-revision 1.4)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count115
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count116
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count117
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count118

(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\
libraries\tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\
libraries\tikzlibrarydecorations.markings.code.tex
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\
libraries\tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmodulede
corations.code.tex
\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen159
\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen160
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen161
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen162
\pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen163
\pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count119
\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen164
\pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen165
)
\tikz@lib@dec@box=\box38
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\decoratio
ns\pgflibrarydecorations.markings.code.tex))
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\
libraries\tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex 2008/01/09 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)

(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibrar
yarrows.code.tex
File: pgflibraryarrows.code.tex 2008/10/27 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.9)
\arrowsize=\dimen166
))
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\
libraries\tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex 2009/09/04 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.6)
)
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\tikz-cd\tikz-cd.sty
Package: tikz-cd 2014/03/08 v0.9b Commutative diagrams with tikz


LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 17, version
               `2013/12/13' of package tikz,
               but only version
               `2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)'
               is available.


(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tikz-cd\tikzlibrarycd.c
ode.tex
(C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\
libraries\tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex 2008/06/18 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
! I can't find file `tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex'.
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex 
                                                  \catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
l.18 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,quotes,arrows.meta}

Please type another input file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex 
                                                  \catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
l.18 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,quotes,arrows.meta}

End of file on the terminal!


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10881 strings out of 493921
 212359 string characters out of 3144873
 246954 words of memory out of 3000000
 13830 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1002 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 56i,0n,57p,452b,63s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: as always, no problems on TeX Live 2013

Comment: No problems here on MikTeX 2.9 x64. Can you add `\listfiles` to your preamble and show us the output file list (appears near the end of the log file)?

Comment: @PaulGessler I have updated the OP's question with the log file, since I too receive this error on one of my systems.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Your TikZ version is not fully updated as far as I can see. I don't have a problem too.

Comment: @percusse The problem is, with Windows 8, I can't even find the MikTeX Update manager.  Sigh...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I saw the Win 8 interface and immediately formatted it. Didn't even bother to try :) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152669/windows-8-cannot-find-miktex-options-after-i-unpinned-them-from-start and also maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159751/how-to-run-miktex-fndb-on-windows-8

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes on my Windows 8 systems, I can access the update manager (Admin- and User-level) by entering the Start Screen and searching for `Update'. The MikTeX managers are the first things in the results list for me.