# Could not start the command. pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex (with extra info to the other questions of this type :p)

Tags: errors, miktex, paths

Ive just installed MiKTeX and TeXmaker using this instillation guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPnfHRE_W_g its been great so far but when I try to fun my 'Hello World' pdf I get this error message:

```
Could not start the command. pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

my TeXmaker is configured idntially to the screen shot in this simmilar quetion: [PdfLaTeX in Texmaker doesn’t work: “Could not start the command”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107110/pdflatex-in-texmaker-doesn-t-work-could-not-start-the-command) . However my LaTeX and PdfLaTeX paths are what the what the suggested answer to that querey already, i.e.,

```
LaTeX: latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

PdfLaTeX: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

When I try to run the file from termainal it brings up the MiKTeX editor TeXworks and the pdf runs fine from there so im really not sure what ive done wrong, Im assuming in need to add a path to TeXmaker however im not sure how to do that

EDIT: sorry for the slow response  this is my configure settings:[image]

[image: Termial output when i run pdflatex file.tex]

Comment: (1) Exactly what OS are you on? (2) Running latex from the terminal does not normally bring op and editor. Please explain in more detail exactly what you did?

Comment: im on windows 10, i did cd to the file directory then ran that file (only one in there) this brought up the TeXworks program with the code i had just written in TeXmaker

Comment: Exactly what did you type on the commandline? I would expect you to type something line `pdflatex file.tex` (for your choice of filename)

Comment: Ah no, i just typed the file name to open it, didn't cross my mind to open it as a pdf. This probably wasnt the best time to ask this question as im going to be away from my computer for today and most of tomorrow

Comment: erh, `pdflatex` converts the `.tex` to PDF. it does not open it as a pdf.

Comment: Does that save a separate copy as a pdf then? Slightly immaterial though, do you have any thoughts why the TeXmaker isnt running for me?

Comment: You can see pdflatex as a sort of compiler, it takes the `.tex` as the input, and gives a PDF as the output. I say something is strange with your windows. Normally TeXMaker picks up the location of pdflatex from the system PATHs. Have you tried the standard Windows solution: reboot? Otherwise try reinstalling TeXMaker

Comment: I'm confused about "terminal ... brings up the MiKTeX editor".  If you go to the directory containing `file.tex` and type `pdflatex file`, what happens?

Comment: ive added a screen shot of the temail to the post, im not sure what i should be getting. in my folder i get a pdf, a text doc and a .aux file all with the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **configuration** needs to be as under::

[image]

The correct command in the terminal / shell window needs to be as under::

[image]

```
>pdflatex story.tex
```

is the operative part of the compile command and results in the correponding pdf file with the same name as the .tex file --in this case story.pdf -- in the same folder-- the message at the end of compile operation is as under::

[image]

Comment: So you think i need to add '--shell-escape' to my command line as thats the only thing different. Thank you for the information, ill try it when i get to my computer.

Comment: leave out the shell escape --thats for certain other dependencies--you may like to upload screen shot of your configuration