# The system cannot find the file specified (error)

Tags: errors, windows, winedt

I have been using Windedt with Texlive since many days. But I stopped using it for a while, and when I now compile a tex file, its giving error "The system cannot find the file specified". I don't know wats wrong. I have used this before. I tried re-installing Winedt, no use. I have recently changed the System Path for installing some software. Has it affected in anyway?? Please help me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). [Verify a latex installation: Commandline/Terminal:](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101890/15717) and configure winedt to the texlive bin although i have no experience with winedt.

Comment: I think you tampered the texlive path in your system. In winedt 7, You go to the `Execution Modes` and in the window that appears check `TeX System` tab. It should have the path to texlive's bin folder. You can also run a diagnosis from `Execution Modes` -> `Diagnosis` tab. Get back for clarifications if any with more details like which winedt version you are using....