# Where is TeXLive after i installed it via terminal ?

Tags: installing, texlive, linux

## What i want

install LaTeX for Linux on Mint 14 OS

## What i did

download LaTex from http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

i installed this package: **install-tl.zip**

successfully installed it via terminal

## Problem

Where is LaTeX on my laptop? i can't find it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Have a look at [Verify a latex installation: Commandline/Terminal:](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101890/15717)

Comment: TeXlive should have asked you where to install; anyway, a log is usually kept in the same dir where the `install-tl` script was: it's usually called `install-tl.log` and informs the base directories of your installation (they must be added to your `PATH` later). AFAIK TeXlive usually defaults them to `/usr/share/`.

Comment: @henrique The vanilla TeX Live installer puts everything in `/usr/local/texlive/<year>`. Only package manager provided TeX distributions (such as for Debian or Fedora) put files in `/usr/share`.

Comment: @egreg is absolutely right. The OP should check [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/5872)

Answer (score 6):

For some *nix systems, you could use [`whereis`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/whereis) command:

> whereis - locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command

```
whereis latex
```

Output example:

```
latex: /usr/bin/latex /usr/share/man/man1/latex.1.gz
```

This should work for TeX Live 2017 on Debian systems.

---

However, keep in mind:

> The whereis utility checks the standard binary directories for the specified programs, printing out the paths of any it finds.

For example on MacOS as @egreg stated:

> the whereis command only looks in the path provided by sysctl user.cs_path, which is /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin. So it doesn't find latex or any binary in the TeX Live distribution, which are installed under /usr/local/texlive//bin/.

So instead, try using [`which`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which):

```
which -a latex
```

> Which takes one or more arguments. For each of its arguments it prints to stdout the full path of the executables that would have been executed when this argument had been entered at the shell prompt.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: @Bobyandbob Cheers, have a good day.

Comment: @U-ways Upvoted!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you cannot *see* LaTeX like other fancy applications.  In other words LaTeX installation does not include GUI.

If LaTeX is installed successfully, then you can simply call it from your terminal.  To check if it is really installed, type this in the terminal:

```
$ latex -v
```

This should output the version information of installed LaTeX.

If that is successful, then the simplest way to typeset is

```
$ latex path/to/file-to-typeset.tex
```

This should generate `file-to-typeset.dvi` in the same directory in which .tex file exists.

Some text editors can call latex command inside (e.g. [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) so that you don't have to switch back and forth from the text editor to the terminal.

Comment: `latex small2e` should create `small2e.dvi` in any directory where the user has write access.  (Or `pdflatex small2e` to get `small2e.pdf`.)

Answer (score 2):

To locate binaries open the shell and type

```
$ whence latex
```

Comment: What is this command?  Do you mean `which latex`?

Comment: It is not "which"! The Unix command for finding binaries is "whence". The was no spelling mistake so I do not see where you read "which"?

Comment: `whence` is actually a shell command (`ksh`), so it doesn't work for example on my Unix system with `bash`. `which` does work, since it's independent of the shell. It cannot find shell commands, in contrast to `whence`, but this doesn't matter here. (just commenting, I did not vote here)

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz Point well taken! I use Korn shell so I am not familiar with bash. As a matter of fact the first thing that I do on MAC and Linux is switching the shell to Korn.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac: `man 1 which`

Comment: @PredragPunosevac -- I'm sorry: I'm not sure how I was to realize you use `ksh`.  I've never used it, so I was unfamiliar with the command `whence`.  It might be useful to put in your answer that one has to be using the Korn shell.  (For `bash`, there is in addition to `which`, `type`, which may be of interest to `bash` users.)

Comment: @jon I own you an apology. I have been using Korn shell and OpenBSD on which Korn shell is default for way too long. As soon as Stefan posted his comment I understood that the down vote was coming from an irritated Bash user.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac -- No worries, really!  I simply thought it might be a typo.  I certainly didn't downvote the answer.  If anything, it just goes to show that I'm probably missing out by never leaving the familiarity of the `bash` world.  Point in case: I only learned about `type` by trying to learn what `whence` did!

Answer (score 1):

Find the installation result files in `/usr/local/texlive`. I highly recommend to read at the [docs](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) for post-installation steps.