# TeX Live issue after update - `fmtutil.cnf` not found

Tags: errors, texlive, updating

I recently updated TeX Live to following version

```
TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Arch Linux)
```

and cannot compile any file anymore, it fails with error

```
$ pdflatex blab.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Arch Linux)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
---! /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

After some research, I found out I am supposed to run `fmtutil --all`, but it also fails with error

```
$ fmtutil --all
/usr/bin/fmtutil: line 395: /usr/share/texmf/texconfig/tcfmgr: No such file or directory
fmtutil: config file `fmtutil.cnf' not found.
```

I tried some fixing to no avail: `texhash`, `texconfig rehash` do not change anything, and `kpsewhich fmtutil.cnf` yields `/etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf`, as it is apparently supposed to.

Comment: possibly related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127529 (similar issue, on windows though). The suggestion there is to run `tlmgr update --self --all` since there's been a structural update recently.

Comment: [Verify a latex installation: Commandline/Terminal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101890/15717)

Comment: @henrique `tlmgr` is not included in Archlinux's version of TeX Live. I tried installing `texlive-localmanager`, but it does not work.

Comment: @texenthusiast every test failed with the same error as mentioned in the post (well, with `latex.fmt` instead of `pdflatex.fmt` for latex, and `xetex/xetex.fmt` and `xetex.pool` for `xetex`).

Comment: You'll probably need to wait for the archlinux packages update, or perhaps tou should consider [downgrading it](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_Packages).

Comment: what does `pdflatex -v` or `pdflatex sample2e` give ? Is the PATH of TeXLive 2013 bin in the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` OK, enabling the executables available. what does `which tex` give ? How many TeXLive distro's (2013/2012..) are there on your computer ?. Try logging out and logging in. Please install [vanilla TeXLive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) which has `tlmgr` `texdoc` for easy install and doc management and remove the TL from Arch Linux. Incase you wish so to have Latest updates and be in sync install the one from TUG TL2013.

Comment: @henrique: Waiting is not necessary. Simply update the system (as suggested below: `pacdiff && fmtutil-sys --all`).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The new texlive-core package requires user-intervention when updating. Running `sudo pacdiff` (this replaces existing files with the new .pacnew files)
followed by `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` should fix it.

For more complete instructions, see: https://www.archlinux.org/news/texlive-2013-update-may-require-user-intervention/

Comment: `pacdiff` is a command that only exists on Arch Linux

Comment: `fmtutil-sys: command not found` what to do?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I was able to solve it with moving all texlive-related `.pacnew`-files into their new locations. After that, the following steps solved the problem for me:

```
mv ~/.texlive /tmp
fmutil -all
sudo fmutil -all
sudo texhash
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on *openSUSE Tumbleweed* after lasted update. I found [a bug request](https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1046277) with a workaround which helped me in my case.

```
touch /var/run/texlive/run-hyphen
/usr/share/texmf/texconfig/update
fmtutil-sys --refresh
```

Don't forget to run it as superuser.