# TeX Live 2013 throwing up errors when using updmap and fmutil

Tags: errors, installing, texlive

I run TeX Live 2013 on Win 7(x64) and was doing fine with updates and everything until today. 
I went for another update, when suddenly the following error message popped up when the updater tried to run `updmap-sys`:

```
The program can't start because runscript.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

The same happened with `fmtutil-sys`.

So I did a reinstall of the whole distribution and the same error occurred during the install. Same error message and all after the installation tried to run `updmap-sys`.

So I am asking myself, what I can do and what is going on.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Did you [`cmd` as `Run as adminstrator`](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/) and type at commandline window `C:\Windows\system32\ tlmgr update -all -self` there was a infrastructure update recently so the above command takes care of it for all updates.

Comment: Just did: Says that no updates are available and then the program quit. I could change the repository, but that would probably not help anything.

Comment: run this `tlmgr update -all -self` 2 -3 times until it changes to a `new` [nearest repository](http://www.ctan.org/mirrors/mirmon)

Comment: Well it removed a package (beamerthemepnhompenh), but the problem is not fixed. When I try to run the programs, I still get the same error messages.

Comment: I think there is `bug` in the recent `tlmgr.pl` update as I can experience it on Win7 64 bit os TeXLive 2013 at `updmap-sys failed <status 53> ....` Also Related Old [Thread at latex-community.org](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=8064)

Comment: I guess that calls for just waiting it out...

Comment: To report a bug in TeX Live installation or infrastructure, please email the [tex-live mailing list](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live). The ever-patient [TeX Live developer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10829/norbert) may be on the way.

Comment: Before we jump to conclusions, let's see if someone else notice same issues. My Infrastructure update was successful and at last `updmap-sys` fired an error as show in log file. for debugging purpose some snippet of [log file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5967735/)

Comment: Well the message you have in your log file is not the same as mine...

Comment: "The program can't start because `runscript.dll` is missing from your computer" was the popup window I got when `updmap-sys` fired an error. I think we are in same boat I suppose.

Comment: Ah ok, so then it must be the same.

Comment: I've met the same question, reinstalling is useless, and the 'runscript.dll' is hard to find.

Comment: But do you perchance have it to share?

Comment: I am having the same problem after a LiveTex basic installation (plain + latex) on Win 7 (x32).

Comment: @Mat Try updating `tlmgr` by running `cmd prompt` as `administrator` and type at window `C:\Windows\System32\ tlmgr update -all -self` since there was a 9 aug `tlmgr` infrastructure update  http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet, sometimes takes time to reach all mirrors so check with most updated one http://www.ctan.org/mirrors/mirmon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was an error from our side. Please simply update again, it will fix the problem with todays update of texlive.infra and texlive-scripts.

Comment: This error occurs again and it's 2018 now. :O Sir help me plz.

Answer (score 1):

Well, all of this got resolved with the present update of `tlmgr`. So the problem took care of itself or more appropriately someone took care of it.