# After upgrading ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10, latex compiling errors

Tags: errors, texlive, texmaker, ubuntu

After upgrading the ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10, when I try the following command in terminal

`$ latex *.tex` or `$ pdflatex *.tex` .

I give the following error with MWE:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
---! /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

Also Texmaker gives error "Could not start the command".

Meanwhile, my Texmaker configuration is as follows:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: I think you may have to rebuilt the format with something like: `sudo fmtutil-sys --all`.  I vaguely remember needing to do that once after an update.

Comment: Thank you @jon for reply, but nothing change.

Comment: Well, it's not TeXmaker, so don't worry about that.  You need to sort out things at a deeper level.  Your last comment means that something like `latex small2e` still gives you the same exact error you first described, right?  Did you rebuild the formats with `fmtutil-sys` and did it run without any errors?

Comment: run `DIFFSEARCHPATH=/etc/texmf pacdiff && fmtutil-sys --all` as root

Comment: @jon yes without any errors.

Comment: @jenson_bo ubuntu says pacdiff command not found. Sorry, I'm newbie on ubuntu.

Comment: related question?: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127517/tex-live-issue-after-update-fmtutil-cnf-not-found

but not sure if it helps

Comment: `pacdiff` is not for Ubuntu.  Are you using the Debian/Ubuntu version of TeX Live (via `apt-get` or the software centre) or installing it yourself?

Comment: @jon, if i understood right you, Texlive installed with ubuntu itself. I have also updated it.

Comment: There is also `fmtutil` (rather than `fmtutil-sys`); can you run `sudo fmtutil --all` and then, if that command works with no errors, try doing `pdflatex small2e`?

Comment: @jon, nothing change. Thank you for your cooperation. I think, i will return to windowz and work with Miktex :-(.

Comment: My advice would be to uninstall all system-installed TeX Live with `sudo apt-get purge texlive*` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`.  Then reinstalling TeX Live, but from [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).  And definitely don't go back to Windows! :)

Comment: You might be interested in [install-tl-ubuntu](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu) which does everything for you to install TeX Live 2013 and notify apt so apt does not try to install the texlive packages as dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error with Pandoc. It was:

```
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.             
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
---! /home/user/.texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

I fixed it by removing / renaming the `/home/user/.texmf-var` folder.

It happened probably because of my system upgrade. That folder probably contains older cache files that are incompatible with the newer latex version that I now have installed.

In your case, the problem is with a system folder.

I recommend trying to find the command that rebuilds these caches (like some suggested in the comments), or, alternatively, uninstalling latex and re-installing it again - probably that will generate them anew.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this problem with

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I hope this help you.

(I sorry for my english).

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but I faced this problem when I updated my Arch-linux box. As suggested by @jon in comments to the question above, `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` solved the problem for me. A lengthier description of potential issue is given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383792/9279).